# element wise matrix operation problem

Tags: numerical-methods, complex-numbers, matlab

I am doing an element wise power calculation, and at a given point, I get a complex value out of real values! I have attached a screen shot from the debugging mode in Matlab
[image]

So, one can see that the first operation is giving a complex number, although both A(8,111) and 4/(gamma-1) where gamma=1.4 are real!

Can any one explain that? I guess for more details, the screen shot speaks for itself.
Thank you in advance

Comment: A tip: it may be a bad idea to use a variable called `gamma` in your Matlab code as it is the name of a very useful common function. Also, in some older versions of Matlab, I've seen a bug where overloading this specific function could cause severe slow downs.

Comment: @horchler ,  I figured that out very recently, and now, I have a tone of scripts with the variable gamma. Is there a way to change it automatically in the entire folder and subfolders?

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way of refactoring variable and function names across files and folders. However, in recent versions, you can edit one variable in a file and then the Editor will prompt to [press shift-return to rename other instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034692/refactoring-variables-and-function-names-in-matlab). There's also find-and-replace. In both cases (especially the latter) you'll want to be careful that you're only changing what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A(8,111)$ is a negative number.  $4/(\gamma - 1)$ should be the even integer $10$, but because of roundoff error its computed value is not quite equal to $10$.

```
> f = 4/(1.4 - 1)
```

f =

10.0000

```
> f - 10
```

ans =

1.7764e-15

A negative number to a non-integer power will get you a complex number.

Comment: Thanks alot...I thought I will have to start lurning the basics of mathematics.